# Webpack throwing error "File to import not found or unreadable: modules/*."

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I am trying to import a bunch of scss files to main styles.scss but in the webpack compilation I get an error
"File to import not found or unreadable: modules/*."
Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import webpack from "webpack";
import CopyWebpackPlugin from "copy-webpack-plugin";
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from "clean-webpack-plugin";
import sass from "node-sass";
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const config = {
  entry: "./src/global/js/main.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true,
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              includePaths: [path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "src", "global", "css", "modules"))]
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-bulk-import"
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/,
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "styles.css",
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: `src/global/css/styles.scss`,
          to: `presentations/shared/css/styles.css`,
          transform(content, absoluteFrom) {
            const result = sass.renderSync({
              file: absoluteFrom,
            });
            return result.css.toString();
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false,
    }),
  ],
};
export default config;
```

And this is my styles.scss:

```
@import "reset.scss";
@import "fonts.scss";
@import 'modules/*';
```

And folder sctructure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulI0P.png)

What should I change in webpack.config to run this well?